# Clear Password TextBox in C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, passwords

In the Update Mode, I have retrieved the Entered Password like below:

```
    txtConfirmPassword.Attributes["value"] = DR["Password"].ToString();
```

But in the Add Mode, I want to clear this TextBox "txtConfirmPassword". I have given like below:

```
    txtConfirmPassword.Text = "";
```

But it is not clearing. How to clear this TextBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clear the value in the same way.

```
txtConfirmPassword.Attributes["value"] = "";
```

**Reason:** When you set the `TextMode="Password"`, You will not be able to set the `.Text` property. In your case you are trying to set `txtConfirmPassword.Text = "";`, It will not have an any effect on Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

txtConfirmPassword.Clear();

Isnt that working?

Comment: there is no such method for textbox

Answer (score 0):

Everything must be so hard with this asp.net try'd to set off/disabled for autocomplete , try'd to change text,try'd to change value attribute ,try'd to format my PC. . . only like this its works :

```
 <asp:TextBox Text="" oninput="this.type='password'" autocomplete="Off" style="border-color:black" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" ID="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
```